# How to properly include custom information into X509 certificates

Tags: x509

I'm working on implementing a web service that uses X509 certificates for authentication and authorization of the caller.

Is it proper to specify the entity type (i.e. "end user" or "device") as part of the subject name, with, say, `OU` RDN?

Is it proper to specify the identity of the entity as part of the subject name, with `CN` RDN?

Is the best place for the authorization tokens to be part of the X509.v3 extensions (I understand authorization info, like "have access to cookie jar", doesn't belong in subject name section)?

If I am to include custom extension values into the certificates, is the proper way to do so is to apply for an OID (through PEN), and create child OID(s) that designate authorization information, and use these OID(s) as OIDs for the extensions? If that's wrong for some reason, any pointers to how this should be done in a standard way, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proper to specify the entity's identity in the Common Name (CN) field of the Subject Distinguished Name (DN).
For a user or device, it would be appropriate to also specify the Organization (O) and/or Organizational Unit (OU) to which they belong in the Subject DN.  There is also the User ID (UID) component.

There is a standard profile of X.509 for authorization assertions [specified in RFC 5755](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5755).  An *attribute certificate* bears one or more attributes about an identity such at group membership, role, clearance level, etc, as well as referencing the *public key certificate* (that is, the usual kind of X.509 certificate) of the identity to which the authorization information applies.

This standardized approach avoids any need to devise custom X.509 extensions, and hence, apply for an official OID (which is just as well, because I don't know the "offical" procedure for this.)

Comment: IMO, applying for PEN gets you OID you can use for your stuff. Puppet's done so: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_attributes_extensions.html
Thank you for the RFC reference, these standard attributes most likely cover what I need.

Comment: However, attribute certificates are largely unsupported, it's hard to find software that creates and manages them, plus I don't think I can transmit them as part of establishing SSL. I do, however, see, how this would be a proper way of doing things :)

Comment: [RFC 5878](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5878) defines TLS extensions for transmitting authorization assertions (both X.509 ACs and SAML assertions).  Unsure which implementations support it (if any).

Comment: Actually, RFC 5878 has a variety of problems.  The more generic RFC 4680 [Supplemental Data](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4680) extension can be used to pass additional data in the TLS handshake.  GnuTLS apparently has support for it.

Comment: @PawelVeselov I have exactly this problem. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @MosheKravchik use RDNs where possible, attributes with well known IDs when possible, or with our own OIDs when nothing else fit.